# Ubuntu 20.04 cd : bash too many arguments error

Tags: 20.04, ros

I'm running into too many arguments error when sourcing a file from a certain location as below:

```
joesan@joesan-InfinityBook-S-14-v5:~$ source '/opt/ros/noetic/setup.bash'
bash: cd: too many arguments
```

I tried using double quotes, without quotes, but this error is persistent. Any idea why this happens?

Here is the contents of the setup.bash file:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
# generated from catkin/cmake/templates/setup.bash.in

CATKIN_SHELL=bash

# source setup.sh from same directory as this file
_CATKIN_SETUP_DIR=$(builtin cd "`dirname "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}"`" > /dev/null && pwd)
. "$_CATKIN_SETUP_DIR/setup.sh"
```

Comment: The cause of the issue is in one of the lines of the script you are sourcing.

Comment: You mean in the setup.bash? It is a pretty standard file that came with the ROS installation!

Comment: Try `PS4=' ${BASH_SOURCE}:$FUNCNAME:$LINENO: ' source '/opt/ros/noetic/setup.bash'`

Comment: Could you post that as an answer? What is that PS4?